# Impossible to get Attachments Outside Wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, customization, attachments

My page (outside the wordpress install) begins something like this:

```
global $wpdb, $wp_query; 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
include_once 'word/wp-blog-header.php';

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'  => 10,
  'post_type'       => 'post'
);
$queryObject = new WP_Query($args);
```

I start the loop like so:

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
```

In the loop I call this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
```

But nothing is returned.

```
print_r(get_post(4));
```

(Where 4 is the id of an attachment) also returns nothing.

Calling

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

echoes the post content, minus the gallery  - which also doesn't get rendered, but the shortcode is removed.

Inside wordpress everything works fine, outside it seems that attachments are simply ignored. Why does this happen? Is there a workaround? Is there something wrong with my query?

.

.

.

**I found an alternative solution to my original problem - using a subdirectory, but I still feel this is a valid question. The original is here:**

I'm using the wordpress engine as a CMS for a website that can't be integrated into wordpress right now because of time constraints (but will be eventually), so I need to get hold of things like post thumbnails outside of the wordpress directory. I'm using the following to set up my loop:

```
global $wpdb, $wp_query; 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
include_once 'word/wp-blog-header.php';
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'  => 10,
  'post_type'       => 'leather_swatch'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

However, in index.php this works, but returns nothing in my external loop:

```
$thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($thumb).'" />';
```

What I find really odd is that

```
print_r(get_post($thumb));
```

returns a post object inside the wordpress directory, but nothing in my custom loop - it doesn't recognise attachments. However I can still print out the content of my post type in the custom loop using the standard the_content() function.

Can anyone illuminate what's going on/how I might fix this? I don't really want to use custom meta data to replicate standard functionality.

Comment: That's a classical X/Y-Problem. Could you please explain _why_ your site can't get integrated into WordPress?

Comment: It's got a lot of custom javascript, as well as a home rolled CMS (which is very buggy, hence why I want to migrate to wordpress). It'll take longer than I've been allocated to do the integration right now, and what I'm attempting seemed like a decent stop-gap solution, as well as a way to start migration. That aside though, this seems like very odd behaviour for wordpress and I'd be interested to know more regardless.

Comment: Might this get you started? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112157/13676

Comment: The problem isn't so much that I can't get the image from a URL, but moreso that I can't get the URL in the first place. Oddly wp_get_attachment_link() works, but that returns a link to the wordpress media page, whereas I need the image src.

All attachments load fine inside the actual wordpress install, the problem only happens when I try to get the image src outside the main WP dir

Answer (score 1):

Your older code seems to work just fine, if there were issues with it - something else caused them.

Your updated version seems to take a step back since your loop is written like main loop and is not using `$queryObject` that you set up.