# Uploaded images not showing properly using wordpress

Tags: images, attachments

I need to insert post programatically in wordpress.. I finished to insert title and content.. But image is not uploaded and attached.. Can you suggest me..

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
      array(
        'post_author'   => $user->ID,
            'post_title'    => $Title,
            'post_content'   =>$Content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'   => 'post',
            'guid'      =>      $site_url . '/?p=' . $post_id
      )
    );


$Featured_image = http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51l-rEon-NL._SL110_.jpg;
$year = date("Y");   
$month = date("m"); 
$url = '/wp-content/uploads/'. $year . '/' . $month . '/'  . basename($Featured_image);

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $Featured_image ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $Featured_image ), 
'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $Featured_image )),
'post_content'   => '',
'post_status'    => 'inherit',
'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

// Insert the attachment.

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment,  $year . '/' . $month . '/'  . basename($Featured_image) ,  $post_id );

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $url );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

I tried this, but image is displaying in media like this,

[image]

At the same time, Image is not storing in uploads folder.. I dont know how to fix this issue.. Can anyone suggest me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called [`media_sideload_image($file, $post_id, $desc, $return);`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/) to download an image from the specified URL and attach it to a post. You can use it.

It asked following Parameters.

- $file : (string) (Required) The URL of the image to download.
- $post_id : (int) (Required) The post ID the media is to be associated
  with.
- $desc : (string) (Optional) Description of the image. Default value: null
- $return : (string) (Optional) Accepts 'html' (image tag html) or
  'src' (URL). Default value: 'html'

It return populated HTML img tag on success, WP_Error object otherwise.

Comment: $url=http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51l-rEon-NL._SL110_.jpg;      $post_id=4;      $image =media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id, $desc = null, $return = 'html' );  I used Like this but it does not upload anything..

Comment: Your url missing `http://` and if you are using `media_sideload_image();` in frontend you have to use `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');` also. Read the documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image

Comment: Thank You so much.. Image is uploaded.. But Can you say how to fix it as featured image for post..

Comment: You can get a idea from this answer for it. (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112157/106350)